# torch.utils.data.DataLoader - why it adds a dimension

Tags: mnist, pytorch-dataloader

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),])
trainset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)            # A
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset.train_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True) # B

dataiter = iter(trainloader)     
images, labels = dataiter.next() # A
images         = dataiter.next() # B
images.shape
```

Why the code above, approach #A gives torch.Size([64, 1, 28, 28]) , while #B gives torch.Size([64, 28, 28])? Where does the second dimension with value 1 in #A come from?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second dimension describes the color channels which for grayscale is 1. RGB images would have 3 channels (red, green and blue) and would look something like `64, 3, W, H`.
So when working with CNNs your data normally has to be in shape `batchsize, channels, width, height` therefore `64, 1, 28, 28` is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain where the channel information is saved or generated? I tried dir(trainset), but didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: hm what do you mean exactly by sotred/generated? All the pixels of the MNIST images are described by a value in range 0-1. So each pixel is one value. If you would have a RGB image each pixel would have three differen 0-1 values and therefore three channels

Comment: Sorry, let me make myself clear. The 'trainset.train_data.shape' gives torch.Size([60000, 28, 28]). There is not additional dimension for the channels.  So I was wondering if the torch.utils.data.DataLoader created channel dimension automatically.

Comment: it probably does